# Question about the Contract API from ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, abi

API spec for `Contract`:

`new Contract(addressOrName: string, contractInterface: ethers.ethers.ContractInterface, signerOrProvider?: ethers.ethers.providers.Provider | ethers.ethers.Signer | undefined):`

1. With respect to the second parameter(`contractInterface`), can I literally just click the Copy ABI to Clipboard button for a contract on Etherscan and provide that to Contract?

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7dc68b7d0915ba5816e617528d6a0576f4143916#code

And would the JSON format of the ABI work as well? (https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x0441ff033652bcEB75a011887F17B5dfC84Ddc6f)

2. With respect to the third parameter, in what scenarios would you input the `signer` vs `provider` since Contract can accept both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With respect to the second parameter(contractInterface), can I literally just click the Copy ABI to Clipboard button for a contract on Etherscan and provide that to Contract?

Yes, at least for [0x7dc68b7d0915ba5816e617528d6a0576f4143916](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7dc68b7d0915ba5816e617528d6a0576f4143916#code) it is fine. There are certain cases in which the contract ABI is different from the actual smart contract, for example [upgradable smart contract](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/upgrading/).
JSON works too, but you need to convert the [JSON object into a String](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) first.

> With respect to the third parameter, in what scenarios would you input
> the signer vs provider since Contract can accept both?

In general, if you need to send transactions, a provider object is not enough. You need a signer to sign the transaction and the signer class should include a provider.

If you just need to use this contract as, for example, a median to subscribe event or to send a call, using the provider is sufficient.